# How to improve search time for searching files in a lot of directories

Tags: find

I have to search for 3 types of files throughout a lot of directories (easily 1k + I think?) some of the files are 13 level deep.

```
installer.jar
Installpackage_*.jar
Patch_*.jar
```

Right  now I am using the find command; I exclude whatever file path I can find so the find command doesn't go through the folders it has searched before. I have set the max depth to 13 (this is the deepest I can find). But still, the search is taking hours to complete.  Any idea how can I improve the search time?

Ps: sorry I didn't post my script as I am currently at home and have no access to the pc in the company.

Answer (score 1):

If your files are readable by `others`, you could use `locate` to find them quickly. A `cronjob` should update the `locatedb` daily (or more).

Here's an example :

```
$ time locate *.db
/etc/aliases.db
/usr/bin/lft.db
/usr/bin/traceproto.db
/usr/bin/traceroute6.db
/usr/bin/traceroute.db
/usr/sbin/tcptraceroute.db
/var/cache/dictionaries-common/aspell.db
/var/cache/dictionaries-common/hunspell.db
/var/cache/dictionaries-common/ispell.db
/var/cache/dictionaries-common/wordlist.db
[a lot of .db files] 
...

real    0m0.036s
user    0m0.032s
sys     0m0.000s
```

Comment: Thanks, but `locate` cannot exclude certain directories. And also, there are lots of file that cannot be read by `others`.